# Diffrence between Are you and Do you

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning difference between below sentences

Are you believing in GOD and Do you believing in GOD

Answer (score 2):

The present continuous is generally not used when you are talking in such context.

> ***Do*** you ***believe*** in God?

...would be the right expression.

*Do you believing in God* is ungrammatical. *Are you believing...* seems that you are asking about the belief *on that particular time* or *for that particular time.* Something like... *Are you doing this? Or Shall I do it for you?*